# Geographical Dispersion Heuristic

Tags: mathematical-optimization, geography

I am trying to implement a hill climbing algorithm to decide which locations to choose from a set of locations based on specific criteria. There are up to 5000 locations to choose from.

One of these criteria is geographic dispersion, thus I need to be able to assign any subset of my locations a value representing dispersion.

Each location has latitude and longitude data.

Speed is an issue and that is why I need some heuristic that will estimate how dispersed a specific set of locations (i.e a possible solution) is.

I have tried summing the pairwise distances of each of the locations in my potential solution but this proves too slow.

I then tried the sum of the distances from the centre of all the locations in my potential solution, this proved faster but doesn't work as effectively. Using this approach will favour a few clusters of locations.

Any other suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm curious why summing pairwise distances is too slow. I think of facility location problems as strategic, high-cost decision problems, i.e., an algorithm that takes hours or days to run is good enough for a decision that will be fixed for years.

Comment: Yeah you are right, my problem lies in the fact that geographical dispersion is always a ternary target compared to the other factors, i.e with all other things being equal choose the more dispersed of two solutions. Without geographical dispersion my implementation supplies good results within 15 seconds, I can not exceed 30 seconds. I am basically trying to find a middle ground where I can gather even partial indication regarding dispersion without paying the calculation hit.

Answer (score 0):

First, could you restate what you mean by pairwise sums? I'm asking, because it sounds that you form all possible pairs and that would be highly ineficient. If this is the case, how about finding first 1) the closest neighbors, then 2) the longest path?

1) If I recall it right, you can do this in less than O(n log n) time.
2) If the formed trees are disconnected, you have to find the shortest distances between  trees, too. And because of trees, this is not an NP-complete problem but actually a shortest path alg suffices.

At this moment, with huge suspicion that I didn't understood your problem correctly, how about some kind of deviation on count of occurrences on geog areas, either evenly divided between extreme points or chosen with some prior heuristic.

Can you define or further elaborate the dispersion concept?

Answer (score 0):

Consider three situations:

1. All your nodes are in a dense cluster.
2. All of your nodes are in a cluster, but the cluster is wide.
3. Many of your nodes are in a cluster, but a few nodes are located far from the cluster.

Your sum across all pairwise distances captures (1) and (2) well: close clusters give smaller results than large clusters. How does it do for (3)? Here, a proportion `e` of the total number of nodes `N` are far away, at an average distance `D`. The other `(1-e)N` nodes are a clustered at an average distance of `d`.

Now, how many pairwise connections must be considered? For the clustered nodes, there are `((1-e)N)^2=e^2*N^2-2*e*N^2+N^2` such connections. For distant nodes, there are `e^2*N^2` connections.

Now, multiply these values by the average distances. This gives a total pairwise average of `(d*(e^2*N^2-2*e*N^2+N^2)+D*(e^2*N^2))/N`. Now, assume that `e` is small, we can then neglect terms incorporating `e^2`. Thus, the average is `d*(N^2-2*e*N^2)/N`.

Now, consider your second metric: everyone's distance from the average center point. This does fine on (1) and (2) as well: close clusters have smaller results than larger clusters. How does it do on 3? Use the same `e` as above to represent the proportion of outliers. Now, the average distance of the nodes from a central point is given by `(d*(1-e)*N+D*e*N)/N`. In other words, the clustered nodes are no longer weighted as heavily.

Is there a way you can have a lightweight computation and still weight the clustered nodes more appropriately? I think so.

My suggestion is that you choose random pairs of nodes from your list, calculate the internode distance, and then average over the results. For (1) tight clusters, all the nodes will be close together, so all of the random pairs you draw will be close to the pairwise average you would have got with your calculation. For (2), loose clusters, the same will be true. For (3), a cluster with outliers, you are more likely to draw nodes from within the cluster than from without, so the outliers end up getting ignored.

As you increase the number of nodes sampled, the cluster will tend to dominate the random sampling. I am guessing this will provide decent accuracy with `O(N)` rather than `O(N^2)` time.